# Joystick control for interactive markers

Tags: ros, rviz, moveit, joystick, interactive-markers

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I intend to use a joystick to move the interactive marker in MoveIt (in Hydro) to position the goal state for my robot arm.

My first approach has been to try and adapt code from @danep found here: [link](https://github.com/danepowell/omni_im)

The issue is i am uncertain how to uncouple the Phantom Omni components and instead pair it with my joystick publishing on the /joy topic with type sensor_msgs/Joy.

Does anyone have insight on this or another approach?

Cheers,

Chris

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/175022/joystick-control-for-interactive-markers/) by [anonymous8676](https://answers.ros.org/users/8676/anonymous8676/) on ROS Answers with karma: 327 on 2014-06-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On a cursory look at the linked code, you just need to replace the omni callbacks with one for your joystick. That is, rather than the two subscribers and their callbacks for the omni, you can use just one of each for the joystick.

Then you need to change the transforms from handling the omni's output (a pose in its own frame) to the joystick output (which I assume you want to be a relative change in the marker's frame). Whereas the code you referenced simply copies a modified transform of the omni pose into an 'InteractionCursorUpdate' message, you'd want to modify the current marker pose according to your received joystick message. You can just get rid of any 'stylus' frames, as you'll (likely) just be working in the marker's frame.

I'm not sure how you're planning on mapping the inputs, but for instance, keeping 'p' as the update.pose, pushing forward on the joystick might result in a 'p.position.x += joy.axes[0]' line of code. Or, maybe you want pushing forward to pitch, so you'd have to modify the quaternion instead.

Disclaimer: I'm not familiar with the omni (working with a sixaxis) nor do I work in python (C++).

---

Originally posted by [kramer](https://answers.ros.org/users/2050/kramer/) with karma: 1470 on 2014-06-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [anonymous8676](https://answers.ros.org/users/8676/anonymous8676/) on 2014-09-08**:
Thanks, I was able to achieve the result using this technique of editing the omin functions.